# Batch script to monitor and react to CPU usage for a certain program

Tags: windows, batch-file

I do not know if this question was asked before, but here goes:

Is there a way to write a batch script such that it continuously monitors the cpu usage % of a certain executable program until the cpu hits 0%? Say we have a program called `xyz.exe`, which currently uses up about 2-4% of cpu according to the task manager. After a certain time the cpu hits 0%. I've tried using `tasklist` command as follows, but was unable to tweak it for cpu purposes:

```
@echo off
:loop
tasklist | "xyz"
if errorlevel 1 (
echo xyz still running
goto loop
) else (
goto next
)

:next
xyz completed
```

Comment: Just a general comment, you might want to learn powershell for stuff like querying process properties and calculating conditions. Besides, you wont get happy with solutions which have heuristics to determine outcome.

Comment: Do you mean "check if program is still running" or so you mean "check if it is idle"? If you want to do some kind of aliveness checking, you could also think about using the windows task scheduler. It allows running it signed off, repeating it or even pausing it when system is used.

Comment: if want to do it without `WMIC` you can use `LOGMAN` or `TYPEPERF` (or to use WMI classes through a hybrid bat/vbscript/jscript).Working on it...

Comment: What do you want to do when the program hangs? Usually you want to monitor CPU usage and if it drops below you want to create a memory dump to be able to analyze why it did hang. Then you can fix the application (if you have the source code of course).

Comment: Essentially, the program gets initiated by some user through an UI. Then, the batch script is supposed to run detecting this running program until it "hangs" idle before the script goes on to do another task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `typeperf "\Process(xyz)\% Processor Time"` you can check the processor usage of `xyz`:

```
@echo off

:check
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%c in ('typeperf "\Process(xyz)\%% Processor Time" -sc 1') do (
    set cpu_usage=%%~c
    goto :break
)
:break
echo %cpu_usage%
set cpu_usage=%cpu_usage:.=%

:: 1 is set in the front to avoid octal comparison
if 1%cpu_usage% LSS 11000000 (
    goto :check_process
) else (
    goto :check
)
:: sleep for 1 second
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 1000 >nul 2>&1
:check_process

QPROCESS * | find /i "xyz" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo process xyz  is running
) || (
    echo process xyz  is not running
)
endlocal
```

**[TYPEPERF](http://ss64.com/nt/typeperf.html)**  ; **[LOGMAN](http://ss64.com/nt/logman.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give this a try and get back to you

Comment: @user2759975 - have on mind that you should trim the `.exe` suffix

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   For /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage LoadPercentage') do echo %%a
```

This method simply parses the standard output of wmic command to the for body and an instance variable is created from it ... Hope it helps

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the `wmic` command, as I do not have administrative privileges on the computer I'm using for this particular task?

Comment: Boot the computer in safemode and add your account to the administrative group.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have very restrictive usage over this computer: I'm not allowed to boot the computer at all. It's supposed to remain idle or in use 24/7

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what permissions are needed, the following powershell pipe will query via WMI (the Get-Process powershell object seems not to calculate percentage):

```
gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | 
   where {$_.Name -eq "jusched"} | select IDProcess,Name,PercentProcessorTime
```

Comment: Powershell is unavailable in this specific desktop (XP professionals 2000) I'm using. I cannot install powershell at all.