# Batch script to run tomcat server in case of max CPU

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, cpu-usage

I would like to set a batch script on windows, that will stop tomcat services and start them again when the CPU usage of tomcat process reach its maximum value:

```
SET USAGE_TOMCAT = tomcat_service_usage_pourcentage
SET MAX_CPU= 98% of CPU

if USAGE_TOMCAT > MAX_CPU          
 run TOMCAT_DIR/bin/shutdown.bat
 run TOMCAT_DIR/bin/startup.bat
```

In this case, what are the operation system properties used to define : USAGE_TOMCAT and MAX_CPU ?

Comment: Variables are referenced with percent symbols surrounding the variable name. Example: %var1%  Also, batch files do not use the < or > for comparisons.  Please read the help for the IF command to understand the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script to monitor and react to CPU usage for a certain program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215083/batch-script-to-monitor-and-react-to-cpu-usage-for-a-certain-program)